# SMI generation / detection in GRUB / real mode vs. in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, hardware

I'm trying to get an idea of the frequency and duration of SMI events on a Supermicro X10SAE C226 board (2.0a BIOS) with E3-1245v3 Haswell CPU.

The [Intel BIOS Implementation Test Suite (BITS)](http://biosbits.org/) SMI Latency Test reports 935 SMI during each 15s test. The test reports the same number of SMIs whether BITS is booted from a USB flash drive or from a SATA-connected CD with USB disabled in BIOS.

On the other hand, when the machine is booted to Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), turbostat always reports 0 in the SMI column. Likewise, rdmsr 0x34 (MSR_SMI_COUNT) never changes.

This discrepancy has me scratching my head. I've skimmed through the source code for BITS and turbostat, and they both just read MSR_SMI_COUNT. Anyone have any [hints | tips | guesses] why the reported SMI rates are so different? Is there some reason the hardware would generate many more SMIs in GRUB / real mode vs. in Linux? Is there something that's preventing MSR_SMI_COUNT from working properly in Linux? (Every turbostat output I found with Google has all 0s in the SMI column.)

Thanks for your help!

Frank

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, there is much more reason for System Management Interrupts (SMIs) happening during real mode than when a full fledged operating system is running.

The BIOS Implementation Test Suite (BITS) even [warns](https://github.com/biosbits/bits/blob/19da7046a7303f1de8b53165eea1a6f486757c03/python/smilatency.py#L42):

```
print "Warning: touching the keyboard can affect the results of this test."
```

For example, it's possible that SMIs are required in real mode for such mundane stuff as emulating legacy keyboard hardware (on top of an USB stack that is implemented in firmware). In contrast, any serious operating system drives as much hardware as possible, itself. Certainly, it comes with its own USB stack and driver for USB keyboards.